# UIImage position on screen/window/superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsattributedstring, superview

I want to add a `UIButton` to the end of `NSAttributedString`. I was unable to do that as `NSAttachment` only takes a `UIImage`.

So, I've added a `UIImage` to `NSAttributedString` as attachment and saved its reference. Now i want to obtain the position of this `UIImage` on `UIScreen`, `UIWindow` or `Superview` to put a `UIButton` at the position of image. Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of putting the `button` in place of `imageView`, why don't you add `tap gesture` on `imageView` itself?

Comment: Which imageView? NSAttachment only takes UIImage and there is no imageView. Which imageView are you referring to?

Comment: Maybe with `textContainer(forGlyphAt:effectiveRange:)` and `lineFragmentRect(forProposedRect:at:writingDirection:remaining:)` you might find it. It's just a guess.